# Angular - REInjectorerror NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add a Directive to some html. I get this error:

```
  NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!
    at NullInjector.get (:4200/vendor.js:150837:27)
    at R3Injector.get (:4200/vendor.js:151004:33)
    at R3Injector.get (:4200/vendor.js:151004:33)
    at R3Injector.get (:4200/vendor.js:151004:33)
    at NgModuleRef.get (:4200/vendor.js:161555:33)
    at R3Injector.get (:4200/vendor.js:151004:33)
    at NgModuleRef.get (:4200/vendor.js:161555:33)
    at R3Injector.get (:4200/vendor.js:151004:33)
    at NgModuleRef.get (:4200/vendor.js:161555:33)
    at Object.get (:4200/vendor.js:161232:35)

This is my Directive:


import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {

  @Input() set appDisableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }
}

I import it in a shared directives module: import { DisableControlDirective } from './disable-control.directive';

This is a component where it is set:

@Component({
  selector: 'bi-action-reactivate',
  templateUrl: './action.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./action.component.scss']
})
export class ActionReactivateComponent extends BaseActionComponent {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    super(el, Kind.Primary, Buttons.Reactivate);
  }
} 

This is the HTML where it is set:

      <bi-action-inactivate
        [appDisableControl]="false"
        (execute)="initialInactivateTrigger$.next()">
      </bi-action-inactivate>
```

Comment: is bi-action-inactivate component is custom formControl?

Comment: No, it is not a form control. Just a button.

Comment: Do I need to do something like this: [formControl]="inactivateControl"?

Comment: As per your appDisableControl directive code It only disables formControl. It would disable buttons. To get rid NullInejctor error you can use Optional decorator private @Optional() ngControl : NgControl

Comment: It would not disable buttons*

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `DisableControlDirective` to disable/enable the form-control, then you need to pass it alongside the directive by using `formControl` or `formControlName` directives, otherwise, the `NgControl` won't be provided:

```html
<bi-action-inactivate
  [formControl]="yourFormControl"
  [appDisableControl]="false"
  (execute)="initialInactivateTrigger$.next()"
>
</bi-action-inactivate>

<!-- OR -->

<form [formGroup]="yourFormGroup">
  <bi-action-inactivate
    formControlName="ctrlName"
    [appDisableControl]="false"
    (execute)="initialInactivateTrigger$.next()"
  >
  </bi-action-inactivate>
</form>
```

**Note:** It's recommended to handle the `@Input` changes within the `ngOnChnages` hook, like the following:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisableControl]',
})
export class DisableControlDirective {
  @Input() disableControl: boolean;

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.disableControl) {
      const action = this.disableControl ? 'disable' : 'enable';
      this.ngControl.control[action]();
    }
  }
}
```